# Byte-compiling a file loads macros with `(eval-and-compile)` but not `(eval-when-compile)`

Tags: elisp-macros, byte-compilation

I created a buffer, `test1.el`:

```
(eval-when-compile
  (defmacro dummy-macro (_) nil)
  (dummy-macro s))
```

Trying to compile this file, I get the following errors:

```
In toplevel form:
test1.el:3:16:Warning: reference to free variable `s'
test1.el:3:16:Error: Symbol's value as variable is void: s
```

If I change `eval-when-compile` to `eval-and-compile` I do not get these errors. Why is this?

I'm running Emacs 24.4.1.

Comment: `eval-when-compile` substitutes the *result returned* after evaluating the body, so that only that result is available (as a constant) when the byte-compiled code is loaded/used. What does `(use-package s :ensure t)` return? That's all that's available. IOW, `eval-when-compile` does NOT make the code in its body available for evaluation. `eval-and-compile` evaluates the body at load time (not just compile time).

Comment: Yes, but macros defined during compilation should be available *during compilation*. They are in normal byte compilation: `(byte-compile-file "test1.el")` is error-free. Why are there errors during Flycheck compilation?

Comment: By the way, the `(eval-when-compile)` form above is the entire contents of the file. There is no code that should be evaluated after compilation.

Comment: I see the same thing when just doing `M-x byte-compile-file RET test1.el`, i.e. flycheck is not relevant to this question. I also see that splitting each form into a separate `eval-when-compile` also succeeds without error, perhaps this indicates a bug in Emacs' eager macro expansion.

Comment: Splitting into two `eval-when-compile` forms works for me.

Comment: When I run `byte-compile-file` I already have the `use-package` macro loaded but Flycheck runs it in a new `emacs -Q` subprocess. That would explain the difference, although not why a macro defined during compilation is not available during compilation without splitting into two `eval-when-compile` forms.

Comment: Running this in a recent emacs, I don't see any byte compilation warnings or errors.