# How to prevent "the function ‘->’ is not known to be defined." warning

Tags: flycheck, warning

How do I prevent flycheck from triggering a warning for the following code:

```
(defun file-path-last-segment ()
  "Get last segment of file path for use in snippets."
  (-> default-directory
      (file-name-directory)
      (directory-file-name)
      (file-name-nondirectory)))
```

The following warning appears in my flycheck errors:

```
the function ‘->’ is not known to be defined.
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. That warning just means that the byte-compiler doesn't know whether `->` will be a defined function at the place you invoke it. If you too are unsure then just be sure to load (e.g. `require`) the library that defines it before you invoke the code that invokes it. (It's just a warning.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> -> is a Lisp macro in `dash.el'.

Macros don't follow the usual rules for function definition which is likely why you're getting this error.

You might be able to do it by explicitly requiring `dash` in your file, if you haven't already.  There's another thread regarding a similar issue around elisp macros that might be relevant [Make flycheck's "reference to free variable" work with macros](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17627/make-flychecks-reference-to-free-variable-work-with-macros)

Comment: `(require 'dash)` prevents the warning.  Thank you.